# Property delete unused form in Netbeans with Codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone, netbeans-8

In Netbeans 8.2 if I right click a .java form I don't need any longer it does remove the file from the computer and removes it from NetBeans but after compiling it returns.  How do you properly remove an unused form?

Comment: Tried to do a clean via the top menu and by right clicking the project and clean there.  After every rebuild it recreates the bare file from the Gui Designer.  I figure there must be some reference somewhere that makes it recreate it.

Comment: get rid of the gui design then, I would guess that the java file being created from a gui design is required functionality

Comment: That was it.  I was thinking it should be deleting the .res file from the project as well since the file is associated with one.  It has the option to do a safe delete by searching references and that also didn't do it.  I had to browse the project folder and manually delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't touch the res file.

Each Java file in the GUI builder maps to a .gui file under the `res/guibuilder` directory. You need to delete both (or refactor both if you move a package). It's implemented this way to keep the code IDE agnostic.

Comment: I'd like to see it automatically deleted via Netbeans or whatever IDE is being used.  This way the files don't keep coming back.

Comment: We maintain 3 different plugins and that is a huge blocker to moving forward quickly. That's one of the reasons our new settings UI, our GUI builder etc. are all external tools and why we use Ant as the build system. It allows us to have a single code base that works for all IDE's. Things like detection of deletion and associating it with a GUI file are doable but we'll need to do them x3 and that takes away time we can work on more features... So it's not a high priority.